# SVM: Why are all my training examples getting categorised as error support vectors?

Tags: svm

I am training an online svm using 20 training examples at a time. However, it turns out that the svm classifier is categorising all 20 of them as **Error Support Vectors**. Can someone explain why this might be happening?

The dimensions of each example is 1024x1.

I am using [Dieh'l code for Online SVM learning](https://github.com/diehl/Incremental-SVM-Learning-in-MATLAB)